# Why does my awk statement create a blank txt file?

Tags: awk

I am trying to write a simple batch script to delete duplicate columns (after the seventh column) from a .txt file.

I have tried the following code

```
awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }' input.txt> output.txt
```

but it just creates a blank `output.txt` file in the folder as if it is not referencing the input file.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Assuming `input.txt` exists in the current directory, nothing wrong with your attempt. Are you on some crazy platform, like Windows?

Comment: Welcome to SO, without seeing any input it is very difficult to say why something not working.

Comment: and the logic in your codes won't `delete duplicate columns (after the seventh column)`

Comment: Maybe `input.txt` isn't readable? To debug, run these commands on your terminal one at a time and copy/paste what is displayed there (i.e. each command and it's output) into your question: 1) `head -3 input.txt | cat -v`. 2) `awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }' input.txt | head -3 | cat -v`. 3) `awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }' input.txt> output.txt; head -3 output.txt | cat -v`. 4) `ls -l input.txt`. 5) `wc -l input.txt`

Comment: You might also consider looking at the delimiters in input.txt. If they are not spaces/tabs, then you will not get what you want. You might simply need to tell it what the delimiters are, for example with -F, or something like that.